# Recommended way for observing UI window from within a mobx-state-tree store

Tags: user-interface, mobx, observers, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm playing around with `mobx-state-tree` and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get things like `window.innerHeight` to be tied into my store. I'm completely new to `Mobx`, so I can't immediately imagine how to integrate this using `observer()` (or another related method). There seems to be some great information for doing this purely with `Mobx` in the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html#stores-for-the-user-interface-state), but I'd like to know what is recommended for `mobx-state-tree`.

From what I can guess, I can start by getting `window` using `getEnv()`, following the documentation for [dependency injection](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#dependency-injection):

#### Example.js

```
import { types, getEnv } from "mobx-state-tree"

const Box = types.model({
        width: types.number,
        height: types.number
    })
    .actions(self => ({
        setWidth() {
            const width = getEnv(self).window.innerWidth
            self.width = width / 10
        }
    }))

export default Box
```

#### Test file

```
import {Box} from './Example'

//mock window for testing
const window = {
    innerWidth: 1200
}

const store = Box.create({
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }, {
        window: window /* inject window into store */
    }
)

//Test
it('updates from window width', () => {
  store.setWidth()
  expect(store.width).toBe(120)
})
```

This works when I run it in a test suite.

How would I write this so that anytime `window.innerWidth` is changed `Box` will recompute its width? Maybe I could use `views`, and have `Box` be a child-node for a larger UI store that delegates changes?

Any advice would be appreciated, and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best solution would be to *not* include it in the `mobx-state-tree` and use a separate `mobx` store.

From the `mobx-state-tree` [docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#should-all-state-of-my-app-be-stored-in-mobx-state-tree), it mentions [emphasis added by me]:

> ### Should all state of my app be stored in mobx-state-tree?
>
> No, or, not necessarily. **An application can use both state trees and vanilla MobX observables at the same time**. State trees are primarily designed to store your domain data, as this kind of state is often distributed and not very local. For local component state, for example, vanilla MobX observables might often be simpler to use.

This means that one could use something like the example from the `mobx` [docs](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html#stores-for-the-user-interface-state):

```
import {observable, computed, asStructure} from 'mobx';
import jquery from 'jquery';

export class UiState {
    @observable language = "en_US";
    @observable pendingRequestCount = 0;

    // .struct makes sure observer won't be signaled unless the
    // dimensions object changed in a deepEqual manner
    @observable.struct windowDimensions = {
        width: jquery(window).width(),
        height: jquery(window).height()
    };

    constructor() {
        jquery.resize(() => {
            this.windowDimensions = getWindowDimensions();
        });
    }

    @computed get appIsInSync() {
        return this.pendingRequestCount === 0
    }
}
```

[Note: one would need to modify this by removing the decorator syntax to make it compatible with `create-react-app`.]

**[Here](http://ianjones.rocks/2017/09/18/mobx-window-size-store.html)** is a complete example of building a store for the window-size.